# Python: How to create a list that has duplicates of itself, but inside the previous one?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a `list` that's inside another `list` and so on.

Example:

`[[[]]]`
becomes
`[[[[]]]]`

Here is my code:

```
startlist = []

def add_seq(list):
    try:
        list.append([])
    except:
        startlist.append([])
        return startlist
    else:
        return list


add_seq(startlist)

print(startlist)

add_seq(startlist[-1])

print(startlist)

add_seq(startlist[-1][-1])

print(startlist)
```

But, I want to use the function in a loop, and the index changes (`startlist[-1]` becomes `startlist[-1][-1]`)

Is there a way to change the index so that I can add more lists to the list?

Comment: Maybe it's better to start with the innermost list innerlist1=[], then the 2nd innermost list, do innerlist2[0]=innerlist1, then innerlist3[0]=innerlist2.

Comment: I'm not sure what the goal is, but wouldn't it be easier to enclose in another list, e.g. `startlist = [startlist]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would construct the nesting layers as string and then evaluate the expression. You can store each layer in a results list to be easily accessible afterwards:

```
"""
Example:

r[0] - [3]
r[1] - [[3]]
r[2] - [[[3]]]

"""
import ast

start = [3]
depth = 3
r = []

for level in range(depth):
    r.append(ast.literal_eval('[' * level + str(start) + ']' * level))
    print(r[level])
```